# Save user input data

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a solution to my problem for quite some time. This is the web app that does some calculations.

https://nicolasbg87.github.io/upwork-style-number/index.html

I'd like to know if it's possible to save user input to an online database so it can be opened and edited. It'd have to autofill all the input fields once called. I was also thinking about the option to save whole page already filled and just store it as it is.

I have to mention that it won't always have the same amount of `<tr>`s inside each table, and that complicates the whole process for me.

I'm running out of ideas and would be very thankful if anyone could assist me in this matter.

Comment: you hope that the data shall be stored online and can be accessed elsewhere?

Comment: Na, just so when the data is called, it auto fills all the input fields so the user can edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options, store the data in the client, this means to store in the `localStorage` of the browser (this only will let availability of information for the client that store it and not share the data with other users or from the other computer). The other option is as you say store in a database but this will require to you use a backend Technology like PHP, Java, Ruby, Python, etc. And a database engine as MySQL, Postgress, and so on. And the others NoSQL like MongoDB, Redis, etc.

According to I see in the webpage the information is well structured and wouldn't be complicated to store it.

Comment: Thanks, Jose. At least I won't be wasting time on research now when I know that it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

In Html, it is not possible.  To store data in a database would require another language.  If you used Javascript it would be possible, but it would be really insecure and very difficult.  I suggest using PHP and Mysql to do it, for the best outcome.  So basically Html is not a database language and requires a backend language.